# I am getting this werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError

Tags: html, python-3.x, tensorflow, flask, backend

I can't figure out why. It must be something with my setup because the same thing is happening in different applications. I set up a very simple model with minimal code to demonstrate.
I am getting this werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError when I try to run my flask app. [Click to see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfLxb.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Friend Chatbot</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
      <div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
User: {{u_inp}}
</div>
<div class="alert alert-dark" role="alert">
  Chatter: {{b_resp}}
</div>


    <form  action="/process" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Friend Chatbot</label>
    <input type="text" name="inp" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Talk to my friend"><br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and Here is my python code

```
import pickle
import json
import random
import tflearn
import numpy as np
import tensorflow
import nltk
from nltk.stem.lancaster import LancasterStemmer
from flask import Flask,render_template,request

app = Flask(__name__)

stemmer = LancasterStemmer()

with open("dataset.json",encoding="utf8") as file:
    data = json.load(file)

words = []
with open("data.pickle","rb") as f:
    words,labels,training,output = pickle.load(f)

tensorflow.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)

model = tflearn.DNN(net)

model.load("model.tflearn")

def bag_of_words(s,words):
    bag = [0 for _ in range(len(words))]
    s_words = nltk.word_tokenize(s)
    s_words = [stemmer.stem(word.lower()) for word in s_words]

    for ss in s_words:
        for i, w in enumerate(words):
            if w == ss:
                bag[i] = 1
    return np.array(bag)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('chat.html')

@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET','POST'])
def chat():
    inp = request.form['inp']
    if inp.lower() == "quit" or "end":
        return None
    results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
    #print(results)
    results_index = np.argmax(results)
    tag = labels[results_index]

    for tg in data["intents"]:
        if tg["tag"] == tag:
            responses = tg["responses"]
    resp = random.choice(responses)   

    return render_template('chat.html',u_inp=inp,b_resp=resp)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are by default rendering `chat.html` on `URL/chat`.
On page load, it will be considered as `GET` method, but `request.form` accepts only POST method.
On page load you are trying to access key `inp = request.form['inp']` which is not present. That's why it throws an error `400 bad request` saying no key is existing on page load.

You can add a condition before `request.form` to accept only `POST` method to take the input.
You can modify the code like below.

```
@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET','POST'])
def chat():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    inp = request.form['inp']
    if inp.lower() == "quit" or "end":
        return None
    results = model.predict([bag_of_words(inp, words)])[0]
    #print(results)
    results_index = np.argmax(results)
    tag = labels[results_index]

    for tg in data["intents"]:
        if tg["tag"] == tag:
            responses = tg["responses"]
    resp = random.choice(responses)   
    return redirect(url_for('index'))
  return render_template('chat.html',u_inp=inp,b_resp=resp)
```

Comment: @Nabi Hassan - If you think I have answered your question please accept and upvote, Thank you.